# Setting Docker network as external via Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, traefik, terraform-provider-docker

I'm in the process of building out some of my Docker Compose containers via Terraform. The two containers are required to join a new external docker network, which I previously configured in the docker-compose.yml of each container with;

```
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I've tried various ways to set the network as external (including current example below attempting to label), but on creation this does not seem to be getting configured at the container level. I haven't been able to find a way to declare this - any thoughts?

```
resource "docker_network" "proxy2" {
  name   = "proxy2"
  driver = "bridge"
  labels {
    label = "external"
    value = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Terraform is generally not recommended to manage docker resources, why don't you simply use docker-cli / docker compose ?

Comment: Have you tried importing the network maybe into the resource? Have you tired setting the `internal` argument to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/network#internal) for the Docker network resource, it seems that the network is made external by using the `internal` argument and setting it to `false`:

```
resource "docker_network" "proxy2" {
  name     = "proxy2"
  driver   = "bridge"
  internal = false
}
```